# How do I modify query in Excel 2013 when created in Excel 2016 Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, vba

I created a workbook in Excel 2016 using Power Query. I'm using code to change the query. But I want to be able to run this in Excel 2013 too. How do I modify my code to access the query?

This is my code works in Excel 2016 but not in 2013 or older.

```
Sub UpdateQuery()
    Dim CmdText As String

    'Compile error here "User Defined Type not defined"
    Dim qry As WorkbookQuery

    'Compile error here "Method or data member not found"
    Set qry = ThisWorkbook.Queries("CurrentQuery")
    CmdText = qry.Formula

    CmdText = ... make a change

    qry.Formula = CmdText

End Sub
```

This code runs fine in Excel 2013 but doesn't get me what I want.

```
Sub UpdateQuery2013()
    Dim cmdText As String

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects("CurrentTable")
    CmdText = lo.QueryTable.CommandText

    CmdText = ... make a change

    lo.QueryTable.CommandText = cmdText

End Sub
```

The above returns: Command text: SELECT * FROM [QueryCurrent]
Connection string: Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=QueryCurrent;Extended Properties=""
Command type: SQL

What I really want is to modify QueryCurrent. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround. I don't know if there's any way to modify the original (Power Query) query from VBA using Excel 2013.

I finally realized that I can simply avoid using the Power Query editor. Enter the query in Excel same as in previous versions: on the ribbon > Data > Connections > Properties > Definition tab > enter query and connection string there. Then use the Excel 2013 code to modify.

```
Sub UpdateQuery2013()
    Dim cmdText As String

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects("CurrentTable")
    CmdText = lo.QueryTable.CommandText

    CmdText = ... make a change

    lo.QueryTable.CommandText = cmdText

End Sub
```

Works fine.